# Azure Synapse Analytics failed to execute the JDBC query produced by the connector with Databricks on Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, azure-databricks, azure-synapse

I am trying to write to my Azure Synapse Server from Databricks, but I keep getting the error:

Azure Synapse Analytics failed to execute the JDBC query produced by the connector

The code is as follows:

```
blobStorage = "*******.blob.core.windows.net"
blobContainer = "synapsestagecontainer"
blobAccessKey = "***************"

tempDir = "wasbs://" + blobContainer + "@" + blobStorage +"/tempDirs"

acntInfo = "fs.azure.account.key."+ blobStorage
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set(acntInfo, blobAccessKey)

dwDatabase = "carlspool"
dwServer = "carlssynapseworkspace"
dwUser = "techadmin@carlssynapseworkspace"
dwPass = "*******"
dwJdbcPort = "1433"
dwJdbcExtraOptions = "encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;"
sqlDwUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + dwServer + ".database.windows.net:" + dwJdbcPort + ";database=" + dwDatabase + ";user=" + dwUser+";password=" + dwPass + ";$dwJdbcExtraOptions"
sqlDwUrlSmall = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + dwServer + ".database.windows.net:" + dwJdbcPort + ";database=" + dwDatabase + ";user=" + dwUser+";password=" + dwPass


spark.conf.set(
   "spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat",
   "true")

example1.write.format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw").option("url", sqlDwUrlSmall).option("dbtable", "SampleTable12").option("forward_spark_azure_storage_credentials","True") .option("tempdir", tempDir).mode("overwrite").save()
```

The full stack trace is a follows:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3898875195714724> in <module>
      4    "true")
      5 
----> 6 example1.write.format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw").option("url", sqlDwUrlSmall).option("dbtable", "SampleTable12").option("forward_spark_azure_storage_credentials","True") .option("tempdir", tempDir).mode("overwrite").save()

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in save(self, path, format, mode, partitionBy, **options)
   1132             self.format(format)
   1133         if path is None:
-> 1134             self._jwrite.save()
   1135         else:
   1136             self._jwrite.save(path)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    115     def deco(*a, **kw):
    116         try:
--> 117             return f(*a, **kw)
    118         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    119             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1761.save.
: com.databricks.spark.sqldw.SqlDWSideException: Azure Synapse Analytics failed to execute the JDBC query produced by the connector.
Underlying SQLException(s):
  - com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: HdfsBridge::recordReaderFillBuffer - Unexpected error encountered filling record reader buffer: HadoopSqlException: String or binary data would be truncated. [ErrorCode = 107090] [SQLState = S0001]
         
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.Utils$.wrapExceptions(Utils.scala:686)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:1079)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$5(SQLExecution.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:852)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:1079)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:468)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:311)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.JDBCWrapper.executeInterruptibly(SqlDWJDBCWrapper.scala:137)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.JDBCWrapper.$anonfun$executeInterruptibly$1(SqlDWJDBCWrapper.scala:115)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.JDBCWrapper.$anonfun$executeInterruptibly$1$adapted(SqlDWJDBCWrapper.scala:115)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.JDBCWrapper.withPreparedStatement(SqlDWJDBCWrapper.scala:362)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.JDBCWrapper.executeInterruptibly(SqlDWJDBCWrapper.scala:115)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.SqlDwWriter.$anonfun$saveToSqlDW$6(SqlDwWriter.scala:239)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:377)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:363)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.SparkDatabricksProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:34)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.SqlDwWriter.$anonfun$saveToSqlDW$1(SqlDwWriter.scala:197)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.SqlDwWriter.$anonfun$saveToSqlDW$1$adapted(SqlDwWriter.scala:73)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.JDBCWrapper.withConnection(SqlDWJDBCWrapper.scala:340)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.SqlDwWriter.saveToSqlDW(SqlDwWriter.scala:73)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.DefaultSource.$anonfun$createRelation$3(DefaultSource.scala:122)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.Utils$.wrapExceptions(Utils.scala:655)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: HdfsBridge::recordReaderFillBuffer - Unexpected error encountered filling record reader buffer: HadoopSqlException: String or binary data would be truncated.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1632)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:602)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:524)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7418)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3272)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:247)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:222)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.execute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:505)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.JDBCWrapper.$anonfun$executeInterruptibly$2(SqlDWJDBCWrapper.scala:115)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.JDBCWrapper.$anonfun$executeInterruptibly$2$adapted(SqlDWJDBCWrapper.scala:115)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.JDBCWrapper.$anonfun$executeInterruptibly$3(SqlDWJDBCWrapper.scala:129)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:659)
    at scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:255)
    at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:213)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:292)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
```

I know there are other people that have experienced this problem with Databricks, and I have try to apply the answers to my situation but I can't get it to work.

The full error is:

```
com.databricks.spark.sqldw.SqlDWSideException: Azure Synapse Analytics failed to execute the JDBC query produced by the connector.
```

I am running Runtime 8.3

Comment: Look at https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D53f00001HKHgcCAH/databricks-throwing-error-sql-dw-failed-to-execute-the-jdbc-query-produced-by-the-connector-while-pushing-the-column-with-string-length-more-than-255. This seems to be similar issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you need to ensure the schema exists. I was doing the same thing without the schema already created. I created it manually and my code ran.

Answer (score 1):

I´ve strugled a few days with the same error until I get the code bellow . I´ve also created a SECRET SCOPE, EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE and EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT in my synapse dedicated pool

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df_gold = spark.read.format('delta').load('dbfs:/mnt/datalake/gold')

df = df_gold.select('faceId', 'name')

blobStorage  = "<your storage name>.blob.core.windows.net"
blobContainer  = "<your container name>"
blobAccessKey = "<your storage key>"

tempDir = "wasbs://" + blobContainer  + "@" + blobStorage  +"/tempDirs"

acntInfo = "fs.azure.account.key."+ blobStorage

sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set(acntInfo, blobAccessKey)

dwDatabase = "<your pool name>"
dwServer = "<your workspace name>.database.windows.net"
dwUser = "user"
dwPass = "pass"
dwJdbcPort =  "1433"
dwJdbcExtraOptions = "encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;"
sqlDwUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + dwServer + ":" + dwJdbcPort + ";database=" + dwDatabase + ";user=" + dwUser+";password=" + dwPass + ";$dwJdbcExtraOptions"
sqlDwUrlSmall = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + dwServer + ":" + dwJdbcPort + ";database=" + dwDatabase + ";user=" + dwUser+";password=" + dwPass

spark.conf.set(
    "spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat",
    "true")

(df
 .write
 .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw")
 .option("url", sqlDwUrlSmall)
 .option("dbtable", "SampleTable")
 .option( "forward_spark_azure_storage_credentials","True")
 .option("tempdir", tempDir)
 .mode("overwrite")
 .save())
```